# How can I see Unicode 10.0 emojis?

Tags: fonts, emoji

My Ubuntu 16.04 system will show [emojis up to Unicode 8.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-8.0/), but not any higher versions of Unicode. How can I get [Unicode 10.0 emojis](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-10.0/), like [the T. rex emoji](https://emojipedia.org/t-rex/), to show up in Chrome and GNOME Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [the Twitter Color Emoji SVGinOT Font](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font) by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:eosrei/fonts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fonts-twemoji-svginot
```

Then, reboot.